# Displaying correct value in drop down list

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, combobox

I have a webpage with some drop down lists on it and on in the `page load event` I want the drop down lists to display the text data from a returned value of a sql statement...

```
Dim TypeControl As Control
TypeControl = MaterialHeader_Edit1.FindControl("cboType")

CType(TypeControl, DropDownList).SelectedValue = CStr(DBTable.Rows(0).Item("MaterialTypeDescription"))
```

The `CStr(DBTable.Rows(0).Item("MaterialTypeDescription"))` code returns string `clay` so on the page load event I want this drop down list to just display that.

This is also located in a seperate sub, which is placed after all of the databinding takes place and what not

Edit:
Also have been trying to get this one to work as well...

```
Dim TypeControl As Control
TypeControl = MaterialHeader_Edit1.FindControl("cboType")

CType(TypeControl, DropDownList).SelectedItem.Text = CStr(DBTable.Rows(0).Item("MaterialTypeDescription"))
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you bind the sql to the drop first, then set the index, probably only after Page.IsPostBack = false  for a control type  UI.WebControls.DropDownList

```
DropDownList1.DataBind()

dim x as integer = -1
x = DropDownList1.Items.IndexOf("clay")
if x > -1 then DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = x
```